# Openlayers Zoom based icon size

Tags: openlayers-2, style, icon

I am displaying icon in feature. I want the size of icon to be dependent to zoom level of map i.e. the icon appears smaller in low zoom levels and bigger in high zoom levels. i used stylemap for that but the icon size does not change on zoom change.

```
var styleschool = new OpenLayers.Style({
            pointRadius: "${radius}",
            label:"${name}",
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            fillColor:'blue',
            strokeColor:'blue',
            fontcolor:'blue',
            externalGraphic:'icon/school_color_icon.png'
        },
        {
            context:{
                radius: function(feature){
                    return map.getZoom()*0.9;
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pointRadius doesn't affect size of externalGraphic, you have to set graphicWidth and graphicHeight instead, try:

```
graphicWidth: "${radius}",
graphicHeight: "${radius}",
...
```